# how to create a new table in database

Tags: plugin-development, database, table

I followed the document to create a migration, add a schema version, install migration and add schema codes into `Install.php`. Last I run the migrate up command, but no table is created. Anyone could tell me what is going wrong please?

Comment: You install.php is only executed during the installation of your plugin. Do you want to create a migration on installation or just as an update?

Comment: @RobinSchambach I want to create a new table. If I reinstall the plugin, I'm not sure if any data will be lost

Comment: Usually not. Craft 3 won't delete any data on it's own. If it is your plugin and you didn't include custom logic to delete certain things you can delete the plugin without any issues and install it again. However.. You can just do `(new Install())->safeUp();` as well

Comment: @RobinSchambach what if I just run ```./craft migrate/create <migration_name> --plugin=<plugin-handle>``` to create a migration, and copy the schema code into its ```safeUp()``` function

And run ```./craft migrate/up --plugin=<plugin-handle>```
The table will be created in this way without re-install the plugin?

Comment: is there a certain reason why you want to use the CLI? I never did that because the `(new Install())->safeUp()` method is way faster and easier. I never tried it your way

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I'm following 100%, but in Craft 3, you can add the code necessary to create the new table in your plugin's [Install migration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/plugin-migrations.html#install-migrations).

That will run every time someone does a fresh installation of your plugin.

For the people that already have your plugin installed, you need to [create a migration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/plugin-migrations.html#creating-migrations) that also creates the table.  The code for the table creation will be very similar in both places.

For the latter, in order for Craft to know a plugin has a new migration is wants to run, you'll need to bump your plugin's [schema version number](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/plugin-migrations.html#executing-migrations).